# Reproduce a "DELETE NOT IN" SQL Statement via LINQ/Subsonic

Tags: linq, subsonic, subsonic3

I want to do something like DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3) AND PAGEID = 9

I have a List of IDS but that could be changed if needs be. I can't work out how to get a boolean result for the LINQ parser.

Here is what Subsonic expects I think.

db.Delete(content => content.PageID == ID).Execute();

I can't work out how to do the NOT IN statement. I've tried the List.Contains method but something not quite right.

**UPDATE:** One alternative is to do:

```
var items = TABLE.Find(x => x.PageID == ID)'
foreach(var item in items)
{
   item.Delete();
}
```

This hits the database a lot more though

Answer (score 2):

When you say "something not quite right" what exactly do you mean?

I'd expect to write:

```
List<int> excluded = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
db.Delete(content => !excluded.Contains(content.PageID)).Execute();
```

Note that you need to call `Contains` on the array of excluded values, not on your candidate. In other words, instead of saying "item not in collection" you're saying "collection doesn't contain item."

Comment: What happened when you tried it? It may not be a "bug" so much as an unsupported type of query. That wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

Try .Contains:

```
db.Delete(content => content.PageID.Contains(<Array containing ID's>).Execute();
```

(the above is just an example, might need some polishing for your specific situation)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this works but its not via LINQ

```
var table = new WebPageContentTable(_db.DataProvider);
var g = new SubSonic.Query.Delete<WebPageContent(_db.DataProvider)
            .From(table)
            .Where(table.ID)
            .NotIn(usedID)
            .Execute();
```

I have found that this does work and via LINQ - however it hits the database multiple times.

```
        var f = WebPageContent.Find(x => !usedID.Any(e => e == x.ID));
        if (f.Count > 0)
        {
            var repo = WebPageContent.GetRepo();
            repo.Delete(f);
        }
```

This I imagine would work in one hit to the database but I get an exception thrown in QueryVisitor::VisitUnary

```
WebPageContent.Delete(x => !usedID.Any(e => e == x.ID));
```